# Can I add styling to pseudo-elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to add a styled `button` via `pseudo-elements` in CSS.

```
.class:before{
  content: "button with design";
  /* ... */
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Button is an image?

Comment: Could you expand on *I want to add designed button in css*?

Comment: No it is html tag. Or Something Like that. But i could use too image

Comment: @Simplicius  I have table tag. And i want add something, before this element. But i want to do this with css :before pseudoClass

Comment: pseudo-elements like `::before` and `::after` can't receive any events like `onClick` or even `hover` and `focus` won't work, since pseudo-elements are not represented in the DOM.

Comment: "content" doesn't support HTML, only plain text. You should use javascript. Instead, you can use an image to insert style to the "content" :before

Comment: @Simplicius I no but i want to shoo this button there. is it possible

Comment: @Bru17 how could i add image. Or how could use javascript. Could you show me

Comment: Yes. You can style `::after` or `::before` like any other element, they however don't offer any functionality. https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/qBZQqjE

Comment: @Simplicius thanks a lot. this answer is what i mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an image to :before you can do this:

```
.class:before{
    content: url(image.jpg);
}
```